# How would i center a webpage either with HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

So i am currently in the middle of making a website for a project but i can not get my webpage centered the code and CSS is under, let me know if there are any overlapping issue, i havent done HTML in a while

**HTLM**
Just the home page not much to say, sections are empty as i do not know what to do at the moment due to the fact that im stuck on this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="CSS/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Home</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
      
    
    <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="HomePage.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="Booking.html" class="active">Booking</a>
    <a href="Info.html" class="active">Info</a>
    <a href="Store.html" class="active">Store</a>    
    <a href="FAQ.html" class="active">FAQ</a> 
    
    
        </div>
  
    

        

    
    <header>

    
    
    
    
    
    </header>
    <section id="websiteBanner">
    <img src="Images/Website Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" id="Banner" \>
    <p>
    
    </p> 
    
    </section>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

**CSS**

The CSS is a mix of copyied work as well as my own, 80% of it has been changed to suit my  needs however i am not 100% on how it all works. As i said above i havent done HTML in a while let alone anything to do with CSS

```
/* CSS Document */
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 840px;
    padding-left: 290px;
    
    
}
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: serif;
    color: #222;
}
.section { 
    
    font-size: 1em;       /* Sets text size for section*/
    line-height: 1.4;     /*Sets height of text*/
}


h1
{
text-align: center; /* Aligns the Head text to the center*/
    
}

 
    

.topnav-centered /* Sets width for nav bar*/
{

    width: 818px;
 
}
#wrap {
   width: 818px;             /* Set wrapper's width */
   margin: 0 auto;           /* Center the wrapper in the window */
     
}
body {
   background-color: #ddd;   /* the colour on the edges of the screen */
}




/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 57px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
 
    
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav-centered a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav-centered a.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

/* Centered section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

  .topnav-centered a {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0;
    left: -0.5;
    transform: none;
  }
#infoTitle
{
    text-align: center;
    
}
#Banner
{
width: 818px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 230px;
}
section{
background-color: 
mediumpurple;

    
    
    
    
}
.topnav-centered
{
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

removed `padding-left` on html

```css
html{
    //padding-left: 290px; removed
}
```

added `margin: auto`

```css
.topnav-centered {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```css
/* CSS Document */
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 840px;
    //padding-left: 290px;
    
    
}
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: serif;
    color: #222;
}
.section { 
    
    font-size: 1em;       /* Sets text size for section*/
    line-height: 1.4;     /*Sets height of text*/
}


h1
{
text-align: center; /* Aligns the Head text to the center*/
    
}

 
    

.topnav-centered /* Sets width for nav bar*/
{

    width: 818px;
 
}
#wrap {
   width: 818px;             /* Set wrapper's width */
   margin: 0 auto;           /* Center the wrapper in the window */
     
}
body {
   background-color: #ddd;   /* the colour on the edges of the screen */
}




/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 57px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
 
    
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav-centered a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav-centered a.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

/* Centered section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

  .topnav-centered a {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0;
    left: -0.5;
    transform: none;
  }
#infoTitle
{
    text-align: center;
    
}
#Banner
{
width: 818px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 230px;
}
section{
background-color: 
mediumpurple;

    
    
    
    
}
.topnav-centered
{
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    
    margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="CSS/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Home</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
      
    
    <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="HomePage.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="Booking.html" class="active">Booking</a>
    <a href="Info.html" class="active">Info</a>
    <a href="Store.html" class="active">Store</a>    
    <a href="FAQ.html" class="active">FAQ</a> 
    
    
        </div>
  
    

        

    
    <header>

    
    
    
    
    
    </header>
    <section id="websiteBanner">
    <img src="Images/Website Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" id="Banner" \>
    <p>
    
    </p> 
    
    </section>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: I changed that i did fix a few issues however it appears to still no be centered to the middle of the screen. Much thanks though